# Is it formal to inform readers that a point will be discussed later in the chapter?

Tags: research-process, publications, writing

I mentioned an important idea in a section without developing it.

Is it formal to inform readers that the point will be discussed later in the chapter?

For example: 
This idea will be discussed in detail in a subsequent section.

If yes, should it be presented just like any sentence, maybe next to the idea? Or Does it require special treatment?

Thank you

Comment: I mentally thank the authors whenever this happens. It makes me sure that, at some point, that thing will become clear.

Comment: If your sections are numbered, include the actual number of the section with the discussion.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with doing so. if you would not, the reader might start wondering. In cases where no other alternatives apply then signalling to the reader that more details will follow allows the reader to continue concentrating on the details at hand. If you end up with a situation like this, you should of course make sure that following such a structure is the best way forward. If it is not then restructuring the text is necessary. After all the goal of writing is to provide the reader with the easiest way to understand your writing (the way you want them to). If you find yourself using this form of signalling often, you should probably take a critical look at your writing and ask yourself why this happens. It might be that you are not structuring the text in a good way.

Comment: *"If you find yourself using this form of signalling often, you should probably take a critical look at your writing"* This. I usually tell my students that this sentence has sort of a bad smell. It may not be bad by itself, but if you end up using it all the time you are explaining stuff in the wrong order.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I tried to say but in more general terms.

Comment: @xLeitix I only partially agree. In developing a conceptual structure that is new to the reader this construction should designed around for exactly the reason you identify, but when writing for experts about yet-another-application-of-[something they are familiar with] it often helps to shorten a lengthy argument and reduce the effort of reading. As always it is about the audience you are writing for.